# SSRS add 2 date time Fields

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 datetime Fields in SSRS and I am summing both of them like: `=TimeSpan.FromTicks(sum(Fields!Logout_Time.Value-Fields!Login_Time.Value))`.

The output is correct but is in `hh:mm:ss` format, I need it to be `hh:mm` format.

Answer (score 0):

The below formula calculates this. Don't forget first to calculate your time field in seconds.

```
=CSTR
(
    (
        Floor
            (
                Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)/3600
            )
    )
)
+ ":"+
IIf
    (
        Floor
            (
                (
                    Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)
                    -
                    (
                        Floor
                            (
                                Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)/3600
                            )*3600
                    )
                )/60

            )<10

    ,
        "0"+    
        CSTR
            (
        Floor
            (
                (
                    Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)
                    -
                    (
                        Floor
                            (
                                    Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)/3600
                            )*3600
                    )
                )/60

            )
            )
        ,
    CSTR
        (
        Floor
            (
                (
                    Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)
                    -
                    (
                        Floor
                            (
                                Sum(Fields!YourTimeField.Value)/3600
                            )*3600
                    )
                )/60

            )       
        )
)
```